# Deleting a node from binary search tree error?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying the leetcode challenge of deleting a node in a BST. Mine deletes it but it returns a messed up tree not sure why.

```
struct TreeNode* deleteNode(struct TreeNode* root, int key) {

    if (root == NULL){return root;}
    else if(root->val == key){return root;}
    if(key < root->right->val){
        if( key == root->left->val){
            root->left = root->left->left;
        }
        else{
            deleteNode(root->left, key);
        }
    }
    else if( key < root->left->val){
        if ( key == root->right->val){
            root->right = root->right->right;
        }else{
            deleteNode(root->right, key);
        }
    }

    return root;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the function's return value.

Comment: You aren't deleting anything if the target key is found in the root node.

Comment: In the cases where you *do* delete a node, you abandon one of the deleted node's children.  For example, when you perform `root->left = root->left->left`, what do you suppose happens to `root->left->right`?

Comment: you modify the root->left or root->right but without freeing the old value, you will have memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix some things, and address the case where the node you are attempting to delete is the root.

Additionally, you need to fix how you update the tree when a node is deleted. You might want to consider a function that returns the minimum value node in the right sub-tree. The prototype might look something like `Node *minValueNode(Node *root)`.

Then when you delete a node that has two child nodes, you replace it with the minimum value node in its right sub-tree.

Consider this implementation that deals with Nodes that store strings:

```
TreeNode *removeWord(TreeNode *tree, char* word){
    if(tree == NULL) return tree;

    if(strcmp(tree->word, word) > 0 ){
        tree->left = removeWord(tree->left, word);
    }
    else if(strcmp(tree->word, word) < 0){
        tree->right = removeWord(tree->right, word);
    }

    else{
        if(tree->left == NULL){
            TreeNode *temp = tree->right;
            free(tree);
            return temp;
        }
        else if(tree->right == NULL){
            TreeNode *temp = tree->left;
            free(tree);
            return temp;
        }

        /* Smallest Node in the right subtree */
        TreeNode *temp = minValueNode(tree->right);

        tree->word = temp->word;
        tree->pos = temp->pos;
        tree->right = removeWord(tree->right, temp->word);
    }
    return tree;
}
```